# Optimizing a Parallel selection leading to Parallel excution

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, plinq

I'm trying to find the optimal way to execute the following flow

1. Get list of X identifier from a flow
2. For each X identifier go to DB and get a list of Y identifiers using a complex query (**should be paralleled**)
3. Merge the lists and distinct it
4. For each Y identifier execute a long running task (**should be paralleled**)

All the flow in 2-4 should be done in a different thread from 1, so that once action 1 calls action 2 it continues to do other stuff.

Currently my flow looks like this(this is for 2-4 and called after 1):

```
private void PerformActionAsync(List<long> XIds)
{
     var affectedYIds = XIds.AsParallel().SelectMany(xId =>
     {
         return GetAffectedYIdsLongRunning(xId);   

     }).Distinct();

     affectedYIds.ForAll(yId=>
     {
         ExcuteLongRunningAction(yId);
     });
 }
```

This doesn't work as both SelectMany and ForAll still block the calling thread, I can replace ForAll with new task creation but still  SelectMany will block the calling thread.
How can I perform SelectMany in a truly async way?

Currently my best solution is to wrap the whole method implementation with Taks.Run, the question is if there's a better way.

Comment: have you searched for `Parallel.For` and `Parallel.Foreach`
also the `Task.ContinueWith` ?

Comment: Both Parallel.For and Parallel.Foreach block the calling thread, Task.ContinueWith doesn't support merging the lists. I updated the question with more specific info

Comment: "Blocking the calling thread" is not the same thing as "not executing in parallel". `.AsParallel()` is parallel but not asynchronous. Is `GetAffectedYIdsLongRunning` itself an asynchronous operation? If not, parallel is the best you're going to get -- you can defer obtaining the results with `Task.Run()` and declare `PerformActionAsync` as returning this `Task`.

Comment: As I understand it, up to step 3, your performance is I/O-bound, not CPU-bound. This implies an asynchronous solution rather than a parallel, multi-threaded one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap your code in a `Task.Run` and return that Task. This will make everything run in the background.

The following Unit Test shows the usage:

```
[TestClass]
public class PLinqTests
{
    private static readonly Stopwatch Watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    [TestMethod]
    public async Task TestPerformAsync()
    {
        await PerformActionAsync(Enumerable.Range(0, 10));
    }

    private Task PerformActionAsync(IEnumerable<int> xIds)
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var affectedYIds = xIds
                .AsParallel()
                .WithDegreeOfParallelism(5)
                .SelectMany(this.GetAffectedYIdsLongRunning)
                .Distinct();

            affectedYIds.ForAll(this.ExcuteLongRunningAction);
        });
    }

    private void ExcuteLongRunningAction(int yId)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("Executed {0} at {1}.", yId, Watch.Elapsed.Seconds);
    }

    private IEnumerable<int> GetAffectedYIdsLongRunning(int xId)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("Getting Affected for {0} at {1}.", xId, Watch.Elapsed.Seconds);

        return Enumerable.Range(30, 10);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Getting Affected for 0 at 1.
Getting Affected for 1 at 1.
Getting Affected for 2 at 1.
Getting Affected for 4 at 2.
Getting Affected for 3 at 2.
Getting Affected for 5 at 2.
Getting Affected for 6 at 2.
Getting Affected for 7 at 3.
Getting Affected for 8 at 3.
Getting Affected for 9 at 3.
Executed 32 at 3.
Executed 31 at 3.
Executed 30 at 4.
Executed 34 at 4.
Executed 33 at 4.
Executed 37 at 4.
Executed 36 at 4.
Executed 35 at 5.
Executed 39 at 5.
Executed 38 at 5.
```